# Do people possess the "right to live"?

Tags: human-rights

Regardless of what country of law is in question, is there an *inalienable* right to live, like Thomas Jefferson effectively said in the US Declaration of Independence?

Consider that some force transcending law created the individual (yet that argument perhaps just gets them to the age of moral agency).  Also, that the law sometimes decides to take the life of individuals (a moral issue not really asked here, but relevant to the question and issues of law).

Comment: A "right to live" or a "right not to be killed by the government?" Notably, would a "right to live" for a sick person require the government to provide unlimited funds for medical care?

Comment: @o.m.:  No. It wouldn't require govt to keep people alive, merely not to deprive them life.  Presumably basic necessities "provided by GOD" (food, a place to sleep, eliminate, maybe even love-relations).

Comment: "Presumably basic necessities "provided by GOD"" This is not part of the legal theory of any Western human rights doctrine.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  "inalienable right endowed by our Creator"  T. Jefferson. (roughly)

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen The Declaration of Independence is not a source of U.S. law.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  Really?  How do you suppose the American Revolution was won, the source of being able to make US Law?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen The Declaration of Independence is "spent", you can't rely upon any of its provisions other than that the U.S. is its own country, in a court of law.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148723/discussion-between-ohwilleke-and-mark-rosenblitt-janssen).

Comment: Please clarify - question says "regardless of country" and tag is [united-states].  Which is it?

Comment: @Criggie:  removed united states.  But there is a homeless crisis there, right now, that has gotten way out of hand.

Comment: @ohwilleke: On what possible basis do you claim that the Declaration of the Independence of the United States has no more relevancy?  People gave their lives for that document and still enroll in the military in belief of it.

Answer (score 6):

I will assume you are asking about the scope of a *legal* right to life.

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

See [Section 7](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/csj-sjc/rfc-dlc/ccrf-ccdl/check/art7.html) of the *Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms*:

> **Everyone has the right to life**, liberty and security of the person and the right not to be deprived thereof except in accordance with the principles of fundamental justice.

This is a right *against* the government. To date, it has not been interpreted as imposing any *positive* obligations on the government. See [*Gosselin v. Quebec (Attorney General)*, 2002 SCC 84, paras. 82-83](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/2027/index.do).

See also [Section 1](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/csj-sjc/rfc-dlc/ccrf-ccdl/check/art1.html):

> The Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms guarantees the rights and freedoms set out in it subject only to such **reasonable limits** prescribed by law as can be demonstrably justified in a free and democratic society.

The right to life is not "inalienable." If a person is deprived of the right to life accordance with the principles of fundamental justice, it would not be an infringement of s. 7. Even if an infringement of the s. 7 right to life is found (i.e. a deprivation of the right of life not in accordance with the principles of fundamental justice), it may be upheld if it is found to be a "reasonable limit prescribed by law" that can "be demonstrably justified in a free and democratic society."

[international](/questions/tagged/international)

#### UN Declaration of Human Rights

Under the [United Nations Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/universal-declaration-of-human-rights), there is a right to life declared in art. 3:

> Everyone has the right to life, liberty and security of person.

But art. 30(2) allows that any right may be limited:

> In the exercise of his rights and freedoms, everyone shall be subject only to such limitations as are determined by law solely for the purpose of securing due recognition and respect for the rights and freedoms of others and of meeting the just requirements of morality, public order and the general welfare in a democratic society.

Note that art. 30(2) does not apply to the absolute prohibition against torture in art. 5, because it is not expressed as a right:

> No one shall be subjected to torture or to cruel, inhuman or degrading treatment or punishment.

See Office of the High Commissioner for Human Rights, "[Universal Declaration of Human Rights at 70: 30 Articles on 30 Articles - Article 5](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2018/11/universal-declaration-human-rights-70-30-articles-30-articles-article-5)" (14 November 2018), which says that the only absolute and unequivocal prohibition in the Declaration is the ban on torture.

#### European Convention on Human Rights

The [ECHR](https://www.echr.coe.int/documents/d/echr/convention_ENG) also articulates a right to life in art. 2:

> **Article 2**
>
> 1. Everyone’s right to life shall be protected by law. No one
>    shall be deprived of his life intentionally save in the execution of
>    a sentence of a court following his conviction of a crime for which
>    this penalty is provided by law.
> 2. Deprivation of life shall not be regarded as inflicted in
>    contravention of this Article when it results from the use of force
>    which is no more than absolutely necessary:
>
>    a. in defence of any person from unlawful violence;
>
>    b. in order to effect a lawful arrest or to prevent the escape
>    of a person lawfully detained;
>
>    c. in action lawfully taken for the purpose of quelling a riot
>    or insurrection.

By its own terms, art. 2 does not absolutely preclude the state taking a life. You can read more about the meaning of art. 2: European Court of Human Rights, [*Guide on Article 2 of the European Convention of Human Rights*](https://www.echr.coe.int/documents/d/echr/Guide_Art_2_ENG) (31 August 2022).

Comment: I believe it is "inalienable" because life transcends the law, yes?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I was referring to the "legal" right to live, but then this is what the question is about:  Can the law take away life, if it did not create it?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen "I believe it is "inalienable" because life transcends the law, yes?" No. You are wrong. "Can the law take away life, if it did not create it?" Yes.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  If the law could create an inalienable right, then the law could take it away.  Care to elucidate your position?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen The notion that something that transcends the law is not part of legal theory, it may be someone's internal subjective justification for breaking the law, but that is all. The law not infrequently authorizes taking away life.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  There must be something that transcends the law, otherwise it would have no basis to exist.  Even nathematics and logic, for example, have axioms which transcend any theorems.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you have a *right to live* in the US, but it is not inalienable

It's **right in the 5th Amendment to the US constitution**:

> No person shall be held to answer for a capital, or otherwise infamous crime, unless on a presentment or indictment of a grand jury, except in cases arising in the land or naval forces, or in the militia, when in actual service in time of war or public danger; nor shall any person be subject for the same offense to be twice put in jeopardy of life or limb; nor shall be compelled in any criminal case to be a witness against himself, **nor be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law**; nor shall private property be taken for public use, without just compensation.

Every person has a right not to be deprived of life, liberty, or property without due process of law. This in turn means, that under the US constitution the due process of law **can** take away your property, liberty, and even life legally. Or phrased differently: the 5th Amendment explicitly allows capital punishment.

### In Germany, you have a right to live, but it is explicitly not inalienable

The German Grundgesetz Art. 2(2) reads:

> (2) Jeder hat das Recht auf Leben und körperliche Unversehrtheit. Die Freiheit der Person ist unverletzlich. In diese Rechte darf nur auf Grund eines Gesetzes eingegriffen werden.

> GG Art.2 (2) Every person shall have the right to life and physical integrity. Freedom of the person shall be inviolable. These rights may be interfered with only pursuant to a law.

So in theory, capital punishment could exist in Germany under GG Art.2, but GG Art. 102 does explicitly prohibit capital punishment, making any law that demands such void:

> GG Art.102 Die Todesstrafe ist abgeschafft.

> GG Art.102 Capital punishment is abolished.

But in *theory*, if Art.102 was removed (it is not protected and could be removed or altered like any other change to the Basic Law), then Art.2 would allow to put the death penalty back into action.

Comment: So, if it is not inalienable, then the State can take it away?

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense that people cannot be deprived property ("without due process of law") because there's very little public property that people can claim (AFAIK) and the economic system deprives people of the rest -- a situation unanticipated by the Founders of America.

Comment: Also, as the Constitution says that people cannot be deprived the right to live, then they should have food available or ability to sleep somewhere freely.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen inalienable means it can't ever be taken away under any circumstances. For example, Germany, Art. 1 GG declares that Human Dignity is inalienable.

Comment: That's funny about Germany -- that means I can't insult people.  The idea of inalienable, to me, means that it cannot be taken away without the taker becoming something less than human.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen Insulting **is** illegal in germany, yes.

Comment: How about if you prove them wrong?  That would hurt their dignity, too.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen "if it is not inalienable, then the State can take it away?" Yes. For example, law enforcement can shoot and kill you on purpose when you are a threat to others. Similarly, during a war, the State can draft you and give you lawful military orders that will inevitably result in your death.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  I don't believe the issue of being drafted into the military has stood up in Court as legal.  Of course I can get a law to say that everyone must join the military if I say so (as president), but will it and can it be upheld?  Perhaps a question for another time.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen The constitutionality of every draft in the history of the United States has been challenged and upheld in the face of a legal challenge. Your belief is flat out wrong.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  Upheld by whom?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen "Upheld by whom?" The Courts and the governments that are bound to obey the orders of the Courts. Who else would you imagine would have any authoritative say on the matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148726/discussion-between-mark-rosenblitt-janssen-and-ohwilleke).